# Retrofit2 not reusing connections - many TIMED_WAIT connections

Tags: java, retrofit2

I'm seeing some odd behavior that looks like connections aren't being reused properly.  Running the code below results in many, many open connections in the TIMED_WAIT state (`netstat -an | grep TIMED_WAIT`) which makes me think connections aren't properly being reused or closed.  I didn't see anywhere in the Retrofit docs that stated what does/doesn't need to be closed, but neither `Call` or `Response` are `Closeable`.  I'm able to reproduce the problem using the synchronous `execute()` (below) or the async `enqueue(Callback)`.

I've tried messing with the Connection Pool `maxIdleConnections` as well as the `Dispatcher` used, but am not seeing any improvement.

Using Retrofit v2.3.0 and OkHttpClient v3.9.1

Any pointers are appreciated.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        dispatcher.setMaxRequests(10);
        dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(10);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .dispatcher(dispatcher)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.200.110.201:8084/prometheus-ws/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        final SomeApi api = retrofit.create(SomeApi.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            final Response<String> resp = api.getStatus().execute();
            System.out.println(resp.body());
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface SomeApi {
    @GET("rest/status")
    Call<String> getStatus();
}
```

EDIT: it looks like a major factor in this is that the server is sending `Connection: close` headers back (low `maxKeepAlive` value).  I can change this in my case - though it is still odd to me that this can affect the client so much or that those client-side connections aren't properly closed immediately when it sees the `Connection: close` header.  Is this a bug in Retrofit / OkHttp?